# Issue with foxpro upsizing wizard

Tags: sql-server, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am working on an application where I am taking fox pro data and upsizing it for SQL using that popular upsizing wizard. However, there seems to be a situation where numeric fields are created 1 size less.

As you can see from my image, I have (10,2) , but this is being translated too (9,2). I cannot change the 9, and it is causing me to lose data.

Anyone knows why this such? and is there a better fix other than updating every numeric row in the database to be one more? This is big and will not be the best option for me.

[image]

Comment: Which version of the Upsizing Wizard are you using? If it's not the one available from VFPX (http://www.codeplex.com/VFPX), try that one and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor Hi I downloading one form this link, however it is showing me the same image as above. Can you look at yours and let me know if it is doing the same please?
http://vfpx.codeplex.com/releases/view/10224

Comment: @TamarE.Granor Testing revealed to me that the error may not be with the upsizing. but with FoxPro database numeric not throwing errors on arithmetic overflows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a upsizing many years ago with Oracle I didn't have troubles like this. But for your case the only solution I can think is changing the foxpro type from Numeric to Double